# Finding Duplicates of Multiple Rows in DB2

Tags: sql

I have a table where there can be duplicates that can span across multiple rows.

For example, lets have Employee table with department.

```
DEPTId  Name   SALARY 

1       TOM     121

1       MARK    21

1       SALLIE  34

2       JAY     342

2       BRITNEY 3

3       TOM     121 

3       MARK    21 

3       SALLIE  34 

4       MARK    21 

4       SALLIE  34 

5       MARK    21 

5       SALLIE  34

5       TOM     121 

5       BRITNEY 3
```

Here when I pass the `DeptId` as 3, I need to get `DeptId` 1, as 3 is essentially same as 1.

5 is not same as 1 as it has more rows. All the rows match & then it is a duplicate.

Can I know how can I find using a single query?

Comment: Check this post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989297/check-whether-set-of-rows-exists-in-production

I have posted with the query.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare two sets within sets (employees within departments).

A set-based approach is to do a self-join on the table, matching by employee.  Next group by two departments.  If the two departments have the same employees, then all employees will match.  That is, there will be no cases where an employee in one department does not match an employee in the other.

The `having` clause tests for this condition.

This version of the query uses a driver table to match the departments to the employees.  When the sets do not match, the full outer join will have an unmatching row, which is picked up in the `having` clause:

```
select driver.deptid1, driver.deptid2
from (select d1.deptid as deptid1, d2.deptid as deptid2
      from (select distinct deptid from employees) d1 cross join
           (select distinct deptid from employees) d2
     ) driver left outer join
     employees e1
     on e1.deptid = driver.deptid full outer join
     employees e2
     on driver.deptid2 = e2.deptid and e1.name = e2.name and e1.salary = e2.salary
group by driver.deptid1, driver.deptid2
having SUM(case when e1.name is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       SUM(case when e2.name is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: The above query doesn't work. I don't understand why we need the SUM in the having clause. It doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @RVishnu . . . I got it.  Your explanation is not very good.  The query needs a driving table to get all the possible pairs of departments.  It  then filters them down based on whether there are any unmatching employees.