# Check whether set of rows exists in Production

Tags: sql

I have two similar tables, one in Production and another in Work in Progress.

I need to copy set of records from Work in Progress to Production. If similar set of records already there in the production, I can't copy.

Instead, I need to get the id of the rows that match.

So, I first check whether the similar set of records are in production before trying to copy.

Here is the example

**Criteria in Production table**

```
CriteriaId    CriteriaVal    CriteriaText

1               42               SAM

1               43               Guess

2               324              Sale

2               432              Jones

2               423              Patrick

2               4322             Tiffany
```

---

**Criteria in Work In Progress table**

```
CriteriaId    CriteriaVal    CriteriaText

41               42               SAM

41               43               Guess

42               324              Sale

42               432              Jones

42               423              Patrick

42               4322             Tiffany

43               42               SAM

442               324              Sale

442               432              Jones

442               423              Patrick

442               4322             Tiffany

442               3432             SAM
```

---

In the above example criteria id 41 and 42 in the Work in Progress match to criteria id 1 & 2 in production.

So, before I try to copy 41 to prod, when I check whether it exists in prod, I need to get the id 1 is same as 41.

Also, the id 442 in Work in progress is not same as 2, as it has one extra row. I need the counts as well as the values should match exactly.

I am trying to do in a SQL query, but I am not able to do that.

Any pointers on how to match a set of records across tables will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query I used to solve this.

```
        SELECT CriteriaId FROM CRITERIA JBCRV1, (
            SELECT DISTINCT JBCRV2.CriteriaId AS CRITERIAID 
            FROM WIPCRITERIA JWBCRV1 
            INNER JOIN CRITERIA JBCRV2
                ON    JWBCRV1.CriteriaVal= JBCRV2.CriteriaVal
                AND   JWBCRV1.CriteriaText = JBCRV2.CriteriaText
            WHERE  JWBCRV1.CriteriaId = #{CriteriaId}
            GROUP BY JBCRV2.CriteriaId HAVING COUNT(1) = 
                (SELECT COUNT(1) 
                 FROM WIPCRITERIA 
                 WHERE CriteriaId = #{CriteriaId} ) 
        ) RESULT_TABLE
        WHERE JBCRV1.CriteriaId = RESULT_TABLE.CRITERIAID
        GROUP BY JBCRV1.BEN_CRTR_ID HAVING COUNT(1) = 
                (SELECT COUNT(1) 
                 FROM WIPCRITERIA 
                 WHERE CriteriaId = #{CriteriaId} )
```

I have tested for various conditions & this work.

Thanks everyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy (SQL2005 and later):

```
select a,b,c from InProgress
EXCEPT
select a,b,c from Production
```

Or:

```
select a,b,c, min(criteriaID), max(criteriaID)
from (
    SELECT criteriaID, a,b,c from InProgress
    UNION ALL
    SELECT criteriaID, a,b,c from Production
) t group by a,b,c having min(criteriaID) <> max(criteriaID)
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of syntax usually gets the job done.

```
insert into table1
(field1, field2, etc)
from table2
where not exists
(subquery to check for exsiting records)
```